# Using curl in C on Windows

Tags: c, curl, static-libraries, libraries, libcurl

I have now followed multiple "guides" on how to use curl in a C project on windows with little to no success. I have installed and build a static build of curl using vs-code and I end up in with the following problem, when I build the following code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
 
    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
 
    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
>gcc libcurl_test.c
C:\Users\JAKOBV~1.SOF\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsyNorR.o:libcurl_test.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\JAKOBV~1.SOF\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsyNorR.o:libcurl_test.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\JAKOBV~1.SOF\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsyNorR.o:libcurl_test.c:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\JAKOBV~1.SOF\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsyNorR.o:libcurl_test.c:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\JAKOBV~1.SOF\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsyNorR.o:libcurl_test.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
C:\Users\JAKOBV~1.SOF\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsyNorR.o:libcurl_test.c:(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I saw some that solved the problem using `gcc libcurl_test.c -lcurl` however then all I get is `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl`

I am quite unexperienced when it comes to using C and especially libraries, what am I doing wrong? My file structure is as follows:

[image]

And inside the curl folder is the following files:

[image]

Please leave a comment if I should add more information, I am not sure what is of interest and what is not....

Comment: "-L curl -l curl_a"?

Comment: `gcc libcurl_test.c`: the error messages you bgeta re from the linker and they basically tell you that you forgot to link to the libcurl library. `gcc libcurl_test.c -lcurl`: the error message is telling you that `libcurl.lib` could not be found. Maybe you just need `-lcurl_a` instead of `-lcurl`.

Comment: @kabanus If you mean that i should run `>gcc libcurl_test.c -L curl -l curl_a` insead, I just get `../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl_a`

Comment: @Jabberwocky See my comment to the answer suggesting the same solution

Comment: The `-L` is supposed` to tell `gcc` where to look for libraries. If `-L curl` does not do the trick, try the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Merely including `curl/curl.h` lets the compiler know what functions exist, but it doesn't actually add those functions to the executable. For that, you also need to link with the library that contains the actual implementation of these functions, namely `curl/libcurl_a.lib`.

To tell `gcc` to link with `libcurl_a.lib`, because it is a *static* library, just put its path on the command line:

```
gcc libcurl_test.c curl/libcurl_a.lib
```

Comment: I still get the same issue with `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl_a`. Note that I only have the library in the same directory as my "main file".. the path in the error message seems to be pointing towards some other location? Or am I misstaken? (This is my first time using an external library as you might be able to tell)

Comment: Thanks, however that still gives me all the errors with the `undefined referece` to stuff.

Comment: What im I missing, I followed a guide on how to build the curl library using vs-code found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_mXVZ6VJs4 Should I look for something else?

Comment: That's not VS Code, that's Visual Studio (yeah Microsoft's naming is confusing). I'm not sure the .lib files created by Visual Studio (MSVC) are compatible with the gcc compiler from mingw that you're using (they might be, I just don't know).

Comment: Oh shit I even knew that… just forgot it when writing my answers… How would you recommend me to do it? Im used to Python, there everything is straight forward and there is a "commonly known correct answer" to almost every question, but with C everything seems to come down to preference and "I usually do this or that" answers.

Comment: If that's the cause, simply use VS all the way, or mingw all the way, don't mix and match. The tutorial video shows how to do everything with VS, so why not follow that?